# Snapping of irregular images in iphone puzzle app

Tags: cocos2d

I am working on puzzle app in which i need to snap irregular shapes as they come in contact of one another as i am new to game development so i dont have any idea how to achieve this functionality in my app.Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that each image has an irregular shape, but you don't need to snap that shape. It also does have a bounding box, and you know where that bounding box should be in the solved puzzle. Note that those bounding boxes can collide but it doesn't matter at all! so you just need to check if the bounding box almost as it's rightful position, and if it is, you just need to move it to it's exact position and lock it.

Comment: Actually you don't need to use the bounding boxes, it's simpler to just use the position of the image, but yeah just store a list of where each piece is positioned relative to it's neighbor and snap to those target positions.

Comment: Thanx a lot Gajoo.I got your idea .Could you provide some relevent code for the same.

Comment: @jhocking If rotation is allowed, you'll need more than just the one position, you'd need two corners or position and rotation. Otherwise, yes, just the position will work.

Comment: Actually the pieces are of different shapes such as triangles, parallelogram etc.Now i need to snap these pieces to crete a meaningful shape.

Comment: Yeah rotation is also possible. Pieces can rotate and can flip as well.

Comment: ah I didn't think of rotation, so yeah that would need more info than just position. but @neha the whole point of this answer is that shape doesn't matter at all. Unless you're wanting to snap together shapes that fit whether or not they are correct; is that what you mean? I wouldn't think snapping incorrect links would be desirable...

Comment: Each piece is an instance of ccnode which does not have any bounding box. With the help of opengl irregular shapes are created in ccnode class.In such case how the snapping is possible among pieces.

Comment: @Neha CCNode does have a bounding box function!